# How can I retrieve all objects from a certain date and on using parse.com?

Tags: iphone, ios, request, parse-platform

I am using [parse.com](https://www.parse.com).  I need to get a list of strings that are stored in parse starting from the date that the user started using the app and on.

The only way I can think of is to get all the objects dates, and have an algorithm that tells me whether that particular object is more recent than the users start date, and only display those strings.  I really don't want to do that, as it seems like more work than needed.  Are there any other solutions out there?

Comment: Have you looked at the docs for `PFQuery`? What have you tried? Why don't you want the most recent data (and page backwards if required)?

Comment: Yes I have and I haven't found anything about this specific topic.  I know how to retrieve data using the date and I explained in the question what will try.  I'm learning and I want to do things correctly and the way I explained doesn't seem like the best way of doing things.  Sorry that it was unclear, but I DO want the most recent data.  I want objects most recent from the users start date.

Comment: Ok, are you using `PFQueryTableViewController` or doing all of the data handling yourself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your 'PFQuery' for objects, use a constraint like `[query whereKey:@"createdAt" isGreaterThanOrEqualTo:[PFUser currentUser].createdAt];`.

Comment: Does this work on compound queries `orQueryWithSubqueries` as well? I have a compound query that was working fine, but limiting it to the last 24 hours returns 0 objects without error.

Comment: I also think there is a small typo in the method call: `greaterThanOrEqualTo:`

Comment: `whereKey: isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: `  is deprecated. Use `whereKey:  greaterThanOrEqualTo: `